# What does "crack around the door" mean?

Tags: expressions

Can I use "crack around the door" in the following situation? If I am wrong, could you give me the correct expression? Thank you.

The door of Dad's room was half-open. Through the crack around the door, the wind came in and blew the book shut, then open.

Comment: Through the doorway ... Sounds more natural

Comment: Could you tell me what "crack around the door" means to you?

Comment: A "crack around the door" suggests the idea of an opening  in the wall  that runs around part of the  surface of the door. http://homerenovations.about.com/od/wallsandtrim/qt/plastcrackdoor.htm

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the meaning of [crack](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crack) may refers to the narrow space of a door left  ajar, but as suggested, *through the doorway*  may be a better choice:

> - A slight narrow space, a fissure.
>
>   - *The window was open a crack.*

- ***Through the crack in the door*** (slight opening) suggests that the door had a crack in it.

Note also the expression:

[Crack the door](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/crack+the+door):

> - to open the door (open) and crack the window (open)
>     to open the door or window a very small amount.
>
>   - *I cracked open the door to peek out. Just crack the window a bit to let air inside.*

Comment: If the door opened a tiny crack, is it right to say through the crack around the door.

Comment: If you want to use "crack" you may say "through the crack of the door".